# logstash redis input plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am new to elastic search, logstash stack. 
We have a large number of client servers that will post events to redis server ( local on client machine ). We are looking to centralize these events data and store in elastic search and analyze the data.

Is there a way to forward the data from redis server to logstash indexer running on a remote server that will in turn store the data in elastic search??

logstash-forwarder or filebeat, does it allow to read from redis server and output to logstash indexer?

Thanks,
Divya

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [Logstash's Redis input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-redis.html) to extract from Redis.

Comment: Thanks @chro. But we have a large number of client servers and we don't know before hand about the client servers host information, to set it in the remote logstash redis input .. Instead we are looking a solution where, these client servers can write to the logstash indexer.

Comment: Filebeat is only for reading log files it seems, and Redis doesn't do anything like that on its own. I would suggest deploying a regular Logstash using the Redis input on the client machines and have them output to a Redis instance on your remote Indexer server. Then have your LS Indexer take from that. That way you don't need to know any client information.

Comment: Thanks @chro for the suggestion. The client servers have a memory constraint, it is a lot of overhead to deploy logstash, as it requires jvm. Hence i was looking for a light weight tool like logstash forwarder or filebeat. We are thinking to read from redis and write to log files on client servers and then use filebeat to output on remote indexer server.